# How do I extract Unicode character sequences from an MZ executable file?

Tags: python, regex, perl, unicode

I want to get Unicode strings from binary (".exe") files.

[image]

When I am using such code:

```
    `unicode_str = re.compile( u'[\u0020-\u007e]{1,}',re.UNICODE )`
```

it works, but it returns only separated symbols, 
so when I am try to change quantifier to 3:

Python:
        `unicode_str = re.compile( u'[\u0020-\u007e]{3,}',re.UNICODE )`

Perl:
        `my @a = ( $file =~ /[\x{0020}-\x{007e}]{3,}/gs );`

I get only ASCII symbols, all Unicode symbols are gone.

Where did I make a mistake or may be I don't know something about Unicode?

---

Code from the comments:

Python:

```
File = open( sys.argv[1], "rb" )
FileData = File.read()
File.close()
unicode_str = re.compile( u'[\u0020-\u007e]{3,}',re.UNICODE )
myList = unicode_str.findall(FileData)
for p in myList:
    print p
```

Perl:

```
$/ = "newline separator";
my $input = shift;
open( File, $input );
my $file = <File>;
close( File );
my @a = ( $file =~ /[\x{0020}-\x{007e}]{3,}/gs );
foreach ( @a ) { print "$_\n"; }
```

Comment: Provide such a binary file. Without example input, one cannot see what's wrong.

Comment: How did you turn the exe into a unicode string?  If it is just a normal string then those regexps will never work.  If you are looking in MS Windows binaries then you likely are looking at UTF-16.

Comment: Probably you wrongly understand the `unicode` principles. You are trying to extract groups of 3+ ASCII printable characters (well, they are a Unicode subset). I suppose you want to extract *wide* unicode chars. And do you know the encoding of your desired chars (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc)?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract wide unicode chars. I'm not always know its encoding but in common case it should be UTF-8

Comment: I hope this can help to understand: [link](http://i45.tinypic.com/23u61ie.png)
And this is a code what I use:
`File = open( sys.argv[1], "rb" )
FileData = File.read()
File.close()
unicode_str = re.compile( u'[\u0020-\u007e]{3,}',re.UNICODE )
myList = unicode_str.findall(FileData)
for p in myList:
    print p`
@ArtM, @Nick Craig-Wood

Comment: @peoff, try  `my @a = ($file =~ /\w+/gsu);`, but I'm not sure if it will return what you exactly want.

Comment: Here are full code:

Perl:

    $/="newline separator";
    my $input = shift;
    open( File, $input );
    my $file = <File>;
    close( File );

    my @a = ( $file =~ /[\x{0020}-\x{007e}]{3,}/gs );

    foreach ( @a ) {
    print "$_\n";
    }


Python:

    File = open( sys.argv[1], "rb" )
    FileData = File.read()
    File.close()
    unicode_str = re.compile( u'[\u0020-\u007e]{3,}',re.UNICODE )
    myList = unicode_str.findall(FileData)
    for p in myList:
        print p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone already wrote a utility that does what you want:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

```
usage: strings [-a] [-f offset] [-b bytes] [-n length] [-o] [-q] [-s] [-u] <file or directory>

Strings takes wild-card expressions for file names, and additional command line parameters are defined as follows:

-a  Ascii-only search (Unicode and Ascii is default)
-b  Bytes of file to scan
-f  File offset at which to start scanning.
-o  Print offset in file string was located
-n  Minimum string length (default is 3)
-q  Quiet (no banner)
-s  Recurse subdirectories
-u  Unicode-only search (Unicode and Ascii is default)  

To search one or more files for the presence of a particular string using strings use a command like this:

strings * | findstr /i TextToSearchFor
```

**Edit:**

Try this if you want to implement it in Python, but you'll have to decide what range of Unicode characters you're looking for and search for it as UTF-16LE.  Many pairs of characters look like valid printable Unicode.  I don't know what algorithm `strings` uses

```
import re
data = open('c:/users/metolone/util/windiff.exe','rb').read()

# Search for printable ASCII characters encoded as UTF-16LE.
pat = re.compile(ur'(?:[\x20-\x7E][\x00]){3,}')
words = [w.decode('utf-16le') for w in pat.findall(data)]
for w in words:
    print w
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I want to write such a tool using Python (or Perl). I almost done it, but I have a problem with wide characters, I can not get the words that contain them. So, now I can't implement only this option: -u Unicode-only search (Unicode and Ascii is default). I'll be greatful for help.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now, the `strings` utility was the first thing I tried, but it does not find all UTF-16 strings (and yes they are valid). I think there is a bug in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Win32::Exe;
my $exe = Win32::Exe->new('foo.exe');
my $inforef = $exe->get_version_info;
printf "%s: %s\n", $_, $inforef->{$_} for qw(Comments CompanyName
    FileDescription FileVersion InternalName LegalCopyright
    LegalTrademarks OriginalFilename ProductName ProductVersion);
```

---

When you are dealing with generic UTF16-BE data, use the [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode) library:

```
use Encode qw(decode encode);
my $octets = # extracted from the exe
    "\x00\x73\x00\x6f\x00\x66\x00\x74\x00\x20\x00\x43\x00\x6f" .
    "\x00\x70\x00\x6f\x00\x72\x00\x61\x00\x74\x00\x69\x00\x6f";
my $characters = decode 'UTF16-BE', $octets, Encode::FB_CROAK;
# 'soft Coporatio'
```

Comment: Thanks.
1. "Win32::Exe" - usefull thing but it can't get all information that I need.
2. "$octets" - I don't have a problem with decoding such sequences, I have a problem with searchin such seauences.

I need to find all string as ASCII, as UNICODE which could be for example like this:

    Example:
    Word: System;
    UNICODE (wide characters): \0053\0079\0073\0074\0065\006D;
    ASCII: \53\79\73\74\65\6D;

And I can't write Regexp for searching wide characters. (If it's a problem in Regexp only).

Comment: Nonsense, of course you can! `"\x00\x53\x00\x79\x00\x73\x00\x74\x00\x65\x00\x6D" =~ encode 'UTF16-BE', "\x53\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6D"; # true` ### `"\x00\x53\x00\x79\x00\x73\x00\x74\x00\x65\x00\x6D" =~ encode 'UTF16-BE', 'System'; # true `